# which metric(s) show the difference between object-oriented and procedural code

Tags: oop, metrics, procedural-programming, anemic-domain-model

Which metric(s) could help to indicate that i have procedural code instead of object-oriented code? I would like to have a set of simple metrics, which indicate with a high probability, that the analyzed code contains procedural transaction scripts and an anemic domain model instead of following sound object-oriented design principles.

Would be happy about any set of useful metrics and tools for measuring.

Thanks, Thomas!

Comment: How about the count of "class" tokens in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Some just out of my mind

- relative number of interfaces, abstract classes, etc. (more OO)
- member variable usage per method (more OO)
- number of methods in which the same member variable is used (more OO)
- quantity of static variables and methods (more procedural, specially static methods (some exceptions apply, like factories))
- lines of code per class (more procedural)

These don't ensure your code is more OO or more procedural, but might find helping those.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cohesion and Coupling

Metrics focused on cohesion and coupling should give a good indication that your classes are real as opposed to collections of functions. There's a very readable paper [here](http://en.scientificcommons.org/43055726) which I quote below to indicate why I think cohesion is a good metric:

*"Cohesion refers to the relatedness" of module components. A highly cohesive component is one with one basic function. It should be difficult to split a cohesive component. Cohesion can be classified using an ordinal scale that ranges from the least desirable category (coincidental cohesion) to the most desirable (functional cohesion)."*

The classic measurement of cohesion is **Chidamber and Kemerer's "Lack of Cohesion in Methods" (LCOM)**. You can also look at **Response for a Class (RFC)** which measures the linkage between methods in a class.

You **could consider design metrics such as NOC and DIT** but my own experience is that they are **too crude and easily confused** by classes within a third-party framework.

You haven't said which language you use but there are some tools built around Eclipse so a quick web search for Eclipse based object oriented metrics should yield something useful